# Three way join with linking table

Tags: mysql, sql

This is what I'd think is a fairly common pattern, but I'm just struggling with the appropiate query for it.

```
User Table
id

Member table
id
name

User Member link table
user_id
member_id
```

A user may exist in the user's table, but not have a row in the User Member link table.

I want to select all rows of the User table, and where a user has a link to a member in the user member link table to show the columns linked to them from the member table.

Here's what I've got, but it only gets the rows from the User table that are linked:

```
SELECT user.id, user.username, member.id, member.name
FROM users
LEFT JOIN user_member ON user.id = user_member.user_id
JOIN member ON user_member.member_id = member.id;
```

I should get something like this:

```
user.id   user.username   member.id   member.name
1         bob             null        null
2         alice           10          Alice 
3         jane            11          Jane
4         joe             null        null
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why do you use `LEFT JOIN` for one join, but not for the other?

Comment: Well if I use LEFT JOIN for the second join, I get all the rows from USER, but where there is a matching member, I get a duplicate row.

Comment: can you provide a sample of the output you are expecting? Also, if a user has many members, you can't avoid having duplicate user data

Comment: I've added an example. Each user may have no members, 1 member or more. At the moment with two left joins I get duplicates for users with 1 member.

Answer (score 1):

I assume a member_id in the `user_member` table always has a corresponding row in the `member` table. **First**, join `member` and `user_member`. **Second**, join `user`.

```
SELECT user.id, user.username, member.id, member.name
FROM users
LEFT JOIN 
(user_member INNER JOIN member ON user_member.member_id = member.id)
ON user.id = user_member.user_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using a `CROSS JOIN`

```
SELECT user.id, user.username, member.id, member.name
    FROM users u
        CROSS JOIN member m
        LEFT JOIN user_member um
            ON u.id= um.user_id
                AND m.id= um.member_id
```